# Traefik URL rewrite from subdomain A to subdomain B

Tags: traefik, traefik-ingress

I would like to get all requests from subdomain `subdomainA.domain.io` to `subdomainB.domain.io` with URL replace. I specifically do **not** want to have a redirect as I want to keep the original URL. Is that possible with replace?

I have tried `replacePathRegex`, but even the most straight up case doesn't seem to work (I have a second reverse proxy, used for identity, that doesn't recognize the new URL).

```yaml
apiVersion: traefik.containo.us/v1alpha1
kind: Middleware
metadata:
  name: test-replaceregex
spec:
  replacePathRegex:
    regex: https://subdomainA.domain.io/graphql
    replacement: https://subdomainB.domain.io/graphql
```

Is this possible in traefik (k8s) and if yes what needs to be done?